# Assign a new column to DataFrame according to a value in another row

Tags: python, pandas

I have this df:

```
pd.DataFrame([
    [50000,'01',991,5000],
    [50000,'01',992,5000],
    [50000,'01','tot',10000],
    [50000,'02',777,2500],
    [50000,'02','tot',2500],
    [66666,'01',777,7000],
    [66666,'01',788,8000],
    [66666,'01','tot',15000]],
    columns=['ID','group_code','section_code','budget'])
```

representing budgets available divided into groups, where the lines with total in the `section_code` are the sum of the whole budgets for the specific `group_code`.

I was trying to produce this df:

```
pd.DataFrame([
    [50000,'01',991,5000, 10000],
    [50000,'01',992,5000, 10000],
    [50000,'01','tot',10000, np.NaN],
    [50000,'02',777,2500, 2500],
    [50000,'02','tot',2500, np.NaN],
    [66666,'01',777,7000, 15000],
    [66666,'01',788,8000, 15000],
    [66666,'01','tot',15000, np.NaN]],
    columns=['ID','group_code','section_code','budget','total available'])
```

Which is the same as the first one but with the sum of the whole `group_code` next to each item in a new `total available` column.

I tried accessing the `budget` column at every line with the string `'total'` in the `section_code`, but I couldn't manage to assign it into a new column using:

```
df.loc[(df['section_code']== 'tot') & (df['group_code']== YYY), 'budget']
```

Where YYY is a specific value ( I want it to be independent and the only solutions come to my mind is iterating through the whole rows)

I'm new to pandas so please pardon me if I don't get the things right.

Can anyone please give me a direction for the right solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a different approach: `mask` the rows with "tot" and apply a `groupby`+`transform('sum')`.

```
df['total_available'] = (df.mask(df['section_code'].eq('tot'))
                           .groupby(['ID', 'group_code'])
                           ['budget'].transform('sum')
                        )
```

output:

```
      ID group_code section_code  budget  total_available
0  50000         01          991    5000          10000.0
1  50000         01          992    5000          10000.0
2  50000         01          tot   10000              NaN
3  50000         02          777    2500           2500.0
4  50000         02          tot    2500              NaN
5  66666         01          777    7000          15000.0
6  66666         01          788    8000          15000.0
7  66666         01          tot   15000              NaN
```